# How to scan all registry values recursively in Qt?

Tags: qt, registry

I want to scan all **registry** **recursively**.

I tried with this but i want to scan all four sections at a time.

```
QSettings reg("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", QSettings::NativeFormat);
foreach (QString key, reg.allKeys()) {
            qDebug()<<reg.value(key).toString();
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are limited to Qt? It's not going to be platform independent after all.

Comment: I want to use only in windows. Can I Scan Current user registry recursively  with while loop ?